# db2 snapshot at an instance

Tags: sql, db2

I have a requirement where I would like to get the snapshot od data at an instance in database.

For Eg:

At a given time - T1, EMP table in DB has following values

Col 1    Col2 
1   ABC
2      DEF
3      GHI

However that data has been modified by another resource/s.
So when I checked at time T2

Col 1    Col2 
1   LMN
2      PQR
3      XYZ

Is there any command available in DB2/ORACLE or any database where if, I provide Time stamp,
I can retrieve the state of Data at that timestamp??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both DB2 and Oracle allow you to do that by issuing queries similar to

```
SELECT * FROM EMP AS OF <timestamp> WHERE ...
```

In DB2 the table must be set up as a *system temporal table* ([as described here, for example](http://ibmdatamag.com/2012/04/temporal-tables-in-db2/)) before you can query it like that.

In Oracle the entire database must be enabled for *flashback*.

In either case the corresponding feature must be enabled *before* the data change to allow you to query the original state of data. You cannot make the table EMP system temporal today and query its yesterday's state; you had to enable the feature yesterday.